# match tickers using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract tickers (which are stock symbols is an abbreviation) from tweets, those tickers starts with $ (dollar sign) and composed of Uppercase letters and sometime "-".
This is an example below:

```
str = "VG Acquisition Has The Potential To Fly High $SPCE $STPK $VG-AC price is $0.88"
```

I tries many regex but none of them returned what I need:

```
\b\$.*\b
[$].*\s     
[$].*\b
[$].*\s$
```

I need to match:

```
$SPCE 
$STPK 
$VG-AC
```

Comment: What was the problem with the ones you have tried?

Comment: Use `re.findall(r'\$\S+', text)`

Comment: sometime the tweet contains stocks prices too, like "$0.88" and '\$\S+' will match the price too

Comment: @khaledkoubaa then you need to define more rigorously what the "tickers" are and are not allowed to contain.. if all you want is to exclude anything that starts with a number after the $ then you can simply use `re.findall(r'\$[^0-9\s]\S*', text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pytickersymbols](https://pypi.org/project/pytickersymbols/), if it does what it says on the tin, should serve your purpose well. From the [tests](https://github.com/portfolioplus/pytickersymbols/blob/master/tests/test_lib.py):

```
import yfinance as yf
y_ticker = yf.Ticker('GOOG')
data = y_ticker.history(period='4d')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have suggested something like that:
re.findall(r’\$[A-Z-?]+’, text)

\$ = Start with $

[A-Z-?]+   = match uppercase letter with dash as a possibility. The + at the end for repeatability.

This regex works even with this pattern: ABS-DE-CE

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
re.findall(r'\$(?!\d+\.\d)\S+', text)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/nIucXk/1).

**Explanation**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \$                       '$'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                           and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match 1 or more uppercase chars A-Z.

Then optionally repeat matching `-` and 1 or more uppercase chars A-Z.

```
\$[A-Z]+(?:-[A-Z]+)*\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\$[A-Z]+` Match `$` and 1 or more uppercase chars A-Z
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `-[A-Z]+` Match `-` and 1 or more uppercase chars A-Z
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4WONXK/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/6WGdeb)

For example

```
import re
 
regex = r"\$[A-Z]+(?:-[A-Z]+)*\b"
s = "VG Acquisition Has The Potential To Fly High $SPCE $STPK $VG-AC price is $0.88"
print(re.findall(regex, s))
```

Output

```
['$SPCE', '$STPK', '$VG-AC']
```